# Windows can't access/modify large SD Card Files

Tags: windows-7, sd-card

I have a 32GB SD Card I use with my GoPro.  It's FAT32, and I'm running it on Windows 7.

I have 50 files or so on it of videos from my GoPro.  I can copy all but two off of it.

Those two are the only two that exceed .3GB.

Windows can't recognize them.  If I try to move them from the file explore, it locks up, and then I get the auto play dialogue as if I just reconnected the SD Card.

I couldn't copy them from the command line, not even with robocopy.  It just says 0.0% and hangs immediately when it hits the first one.

All the other files act normal, though if I delete them, they disappear but show up again when I reconnect the device.

Does anyone know what the heck this is?